# What am I doing wrong with my bind function here?

Tags: c++, stl, functional-programming

I wrote my `bind` function which returns a nullary functor because I don't have boost. Though this code compiles fine, it does not behave as I expected. When I input 2 as the number of numbers and try to enter them, the program terminates the first time I hit return. And, when I debug, it segfaults inside `mem_fun_t::operator()`. What am I doing wrong here? And how to rectify it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

namespace MT
{
    template<class Operation>
    struct binder
    {
        protected:
            Operation _op;
            typename Operation::argument_type _arg;

        public:
            binder(Operation& fn, typename Operation::argument_type arg)
                :_op(fn), _arg(arg)
            {
            }

            typename Operation::result_type operator()()
            {
                return _op(_arg);
            }
    };

    template<class Operation, class Arg>
    binder<Operation> bind(Operation op, Arg arg)
    {
        return binder<Operation>(op, arg);
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> vNumbers;
    vector<char> vOperators;
    int iNumCount = 0;
    int iNumOperators = 0;

    cout << "Enter number of number(s) :) :\n";
    cin >> iNumCount;

    int iNumber;
    cout << "Enter the " << iNumCount << " number(s):\n";

    generate_n(back_inserter(vNumbers), iNumCount, MT::bind(mem_fun(&istream::get), &cin));

    system("clear");

    copy(vNumbers.begin(), vNumbers.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Just a note: system("clear") is not a valid command on Windows.

Comment: I thought something like this at: http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=2891, http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/tic/tic0239.shtml

Comment: Why not use `bind1st` or `bind2nd` from the StdLib?

Comment: This also seems like a crazy obfuscation of a very simple problem.

Comment: @DeadMG: Why would you use Windows?

Comment: @John Dibling: I'd be much grateful if you can show me how to do what I am trying to do with `generate_n` using `bind1st` or `bind2nd` and standard STL functions. Without for loops of course. :)

Comment: @Roger Pate: Because I find Linux to be hideously unusable? Linux offers absolutely nothing that Windows doesn't.

Comment: @DeadMG: Apparently it offers "clear". :)  (But I never mentioned Linux.)

Comment: @Roger Pate: That's entirely true :P But of little use. I never have any use for system("clear"), or indeed, any non-Windows OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

istream::get is not the right method to use, as it reads characters, not ints.  You'd need to use operator>> (and selecting the right overload is very verbose), or just write a different functor:

```
template<class T>
struct Extract {
  istream &stream;
  Extract(istream &stream) : stream (stream) {}

  T operator()() {
    T x;
    if (!(stream >> x)) {
      // handle failure as required, possibly throw an exception
    }
    return x;
  }
};

// ...
generate_n(back_inserter(vNumbers), iNumCount, Extract<int>(cin));
```

Comment: @Roger Pate: Thanks. Any comments on the functor are also welcome. And, why isnt such a functor available in STL?

Comment: or `copy_n()` (or `transform_n`) with `istream_iterator`. (no need for `Extract<>`, but then you'd need to write `copy_n()`).

Comment: @wilhelmtell: I'd thought about that, but this is simpler here.

Comment: @nakiya: Because the stdlib only includes the kitchen sink for particular libraries. :)  Actually, the STL was a proprietary library published ~1995 and dealt with compiler support at that time.  It was incorporated into the '98 standard (with a few modifications), but the stdlib has largely been unchanged since then (until 0x, Real Soon Now™).  This is the general reason why boost exists, but you can't use that.

Comment: Go go Captain Lambda Functions solving this problem.

Comment: @DeadMG: I'd really *not* want to see this in a lambda, especially when it throws.  Though defining it close to the point of use as a regular function with a closure (which 0x syntax doesn't allow), could be great.

Comment: @Roger Pate: How is a lambda NOT ideal for this situation?

Comment: @DeadMG: Readability.  The same reason defining Extract far away from the point of use would be, but I think Extract is better — in this case — overall, especially when you consider it might have general use, as nakiya commented above.

Comment: @Roger Pate: How can readability be improved by not having your code inline where it gets executed? We're not talking about the post-optimization disassembler here, either, but the raw code.

Comment: @DeadMG: You're right, we should write everything as a single expression.

Comment: @Roger: That's not even remotely close and you know it. The expression contained within the lambda is exactly the same as the expression contained in the functor, it just has six tons less boilerplate and is inline. You're talking about writing less code and putting that code where it's used, and therefore that's a bad thing?

Comment: @DeadMG: I tried to indicate it was a personal view in "I'd really not want", but I did mention "defining it close to the point of use as a regular function with a closure could be great".